# Excel VBA copying range within filtered data and appending to end of table on another worksheet

Tags: vba, excel

I have a problem, but my VBA is novice and can't figure out what's going wrong with my code.

What I'm trying to achieve is:

**Step 1**. In Sheet 1 I have lots of data beneath the headings in cells B8:BR8

**Step 2**. I filter on cell BE8 for non-blanks

**Step 3**. I copy the filtered data beneath BE8:BN8 (excluding the headings and I don't need all of the data hence I'm just copying a subset of the full data)

**Step 4**. I go to Sheet 2 where I have a populated table with headings in C8:L8 that correspond exactly to the headings BE8:BN8 from Sheet 1

**Step 5**. I want to append this new copied set of data to the end of this table in Sheet 2

**Step 6**. I want to go back to Sheet 1 and delete some of the filtered data, specifically those under headings BE8,BK8:BN8

Here's my attempt which I've tried to adapt from another code:

```
Sub TransferData()

    Dim WS1 As Worksheet, WS2 As Worksheet
    Dim RngBeforeFilter As Range, RngAfterFilter As Range
    Dim LCol As Long, LRow As Long

    With ThisWorkbook
        Set WS1 = .Sheets("Sheet1")
        Set WS2 = .Sheets("Sheet2")
    End With

    With WS1
        'Make sure no other filters are active.
        .AutoFilterMode = False

        'Get the correct boundaries.
        LRow = .Range("BE" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        LCol = .Range("BE8:BN8").Column

        'Set the range to filter.
        Set RngBeforeFilter = .Range(.Cells(1, 2), .Cells(LRow, LCol)).Offset(1)
        RngBeforeFilter.Rows(8).AutoFilter Field:=56, Criteria1:="<>"

        'Set the new range, but use visible cells only.
        Set RngAfterFilter = .Range(.Cells(1, 7), .Cells(LRow, LCol)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)

        'Copy the visible cells from the new range.
        RngAfterFilter.Copy WS2.Range("C65536").End(xlUp)

        'Clear filtered data (not working)
        Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B8", Range("B8").End(xlDown)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).ClearContents
        .ShowAllData

    End With

End Sub
```

I would appreciate any help that you could provide.

Thanks
Jacque

Comment: What went wrong with your code exactly and what have you tried to debug it?

Comment: It just wasn't finding the write columns, and then it was appending the header as well.  Also, the clear contents was deleting all records.

Comment: It's just not enough information or specific enough a question, sorry.

Comment: What additional information is required? I've made it clear the two major steps, one to copy filtered data from specific columns and secondly to append them to the end of the table.  I've provided the coding I'm using, not sure what's not informative enough.

Comment: What would really help is some mock-ups of Sheet1 before, Sheet2 after and Sheet1 after.  I sort of see where you're going but agree with @EileenR that there isn't enough to go on here.

Comment: Hi, Hambone, Eileen R and bobajob, please see mockups in my answer below.  Thanks Jacque

Answer (score 0):

A few problems here:

```
.Range("BE8:BN8").Column
```

probably isn't doing what you expect - it will just return the column number of BE (ie 57).

RngBeforeFilter is doing nothing - you can just use

```
.Rows(8).AutoFilter Field:=56, Criteria1:="<>"
```

You say you want to copy data in BE:BN, but you start RngAfterFilter from column A (ie .Cells(1, 7)).

```
WS2.Range("C65536").End(xlUp)
```

gives the last row used, whereas you'll want to paste into the next row down.

You're clearing column B, rather than columns BE, BK and BN.

As such, try this instead:

```
 Sub TransferData()

Dim WS1 As Worksheet, WS2 As Worksheet
Dim RngBeforeFilter As Range, RngAfterFilter As Range
Dim BECol As Long, BNCol As Long, LRow As Long

With ThisWorkbook
    Set WS1 = .Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set WS2 = .Sheets("Sheet2")
End With

With WS1
    'Make sure no other filters are active.
    .AutoFilterMode = False

    'Get the correct boundaries.
    LRow = .Range("BE" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    BECol = .Range("BE8").Column
    BNCol = .Range("BN8").Column

    'Set the range to filter.
    .Rows(8).AutoFilter Field:=BECol - 1, Criteria1:="<>"

    'Set the new range, but use visible cells only.
    Set RngAfterFilter = .Range(.Cells(9, BECol), .Cells(LRow, BNCol)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    'Copy the visible cells from the new range.
    RngAfterFilter.Copy WS2.Range("C65536").End(xlUp).Offset(1)

    'Clear filtered data
    .Range("BE9", Range("BE8").End(xlDown)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).ClearContents
    .Range("BK9", Range("BK8").End(xlDown)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).ClearContents
    .Range("BN9", Range("BN8").End(xlDown)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).ClearContents
    .ShowAllData

End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi, Hambone, Eileen R and bobajob, please see mockups in my answer below. Thanks Jacque